# Search for model with multiple properties (where properties are in a key => value table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Document`, and a `has_many` relation with `DocumentProperty`.

`DocumentProperty` has a `id`, `document_id`, `key`, and `value` columns.

I'm trying to come up with a query that will let me search for a document with two or more key => value pairs, e.g a document with size = A4 **and** pages = 2, but I can't find a way to do that without writing all of the SQL myself (currently using an ActiveRecord::Relation).

Example table data:

```
| document_id | key    | value   |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| 1           | size   | A4      |
| 1           | pages  | 2       |
| 2           | size   | A4      |
| 2           | pages  | 3       |
| 3           | size   | A4      |
| 3           | pages  | 2       |
| 3           | author | Brandon |
```

With my search, document 1 and 3 should be returned.

Does Rails support this?

Comment: do you have it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, ActiveRecord supports such queries:

```
Document.joins(:document_properties)
        .where("document_properties.key = 'size' AND document_properties.value = 'A4' OR document_properties.key = 'pages' AND document_properties.value = 2")
        .group('documents.id')
```

Comment: Please look closer at my post, document_properties only has 4 columns. In my example, one row has the key of size and value of A4. Size isn't a column.

Answer (score 0):

I have build the models in rails. Try this, computed document_ids first,

```
2.2.3 :002 > document_ids = DocumentProperty.where(key: 'size', value: 'A4').pluck('document_id') & DocumentProperty.where(key: 'pages', value: '2').pluck('document_id')
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `document_properties`.`document_id` FROM `document_properties` WHERE `document_properties`.`key` = 'size' AND `document_properties`.`value` = 'A4'
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `document_properties`.`document_id` FROM `document_properties` WHERE `document_properties`.`key` = 'pages' AND `document_properties`.`value` = '2'
 => [1, 3]
2.2.3 :003 > Document.where(id: document_ids)
  Document Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `documents`.* FROM `documents` WHERE `documents`.`id` IN (1, 3)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Document id: 1, name: "first", created_at: "2016-11-02 14:07:38", updated_at: "2016-11-02 14:07:38">, #<Document id: 3, name: "three", created_at: "2016-11-02 14:07:38", updated_at: "2016-11-02 14:07:38">]>
2.2.3 :004 >
```